# How and why I would use callbacks? My interpretation and needed reassurance

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I've been creating random callback functions this morning with the intent to really get it stuck in my brain on how and why I would use them.

I've come to the conclusion that a callback function is passed as a parameter to another function, with the intent to use the data from the first function to do something in the callback function? Let me know if my own interpretation makes sense or if I'm off base lol.

And I would use these callback functions for the purpose of waiting for the data needed from another function, to make my callback work?

This seems like the weirdest but hardest concept for me. It's like 1 day I feel confident and then a week later am confused again.

Comment: Modern approach is to prefer to use promises rather than callbacks but it also depends on use case for which you have provided none

Comment: @charlietfl Incidentally, promises make use of callbacks.

Comment: If you're trying to wrap your head around callbacks, read up on how modern JS was updated to support those through promises, which are a callback pattern that you don't have to invent after you "understand callbacks". The only thing to "get" when it comes to callbacks is that you've changed the data flow: instead of sending signals back to the caller of a function, that function instead sends its signals to a (or various) callback function(s),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation is correct. A callback is a function that is used to *call back*, as the name suggests:

```
function callMeBackPleaseAndSayWakeUp(phrase) {
  say(phrase);
}

function aFriendWhoLovesToWorkAsAHumanAlarm(timeSpan, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback('Wake up'), timeSpan);
}

aFriendWhoLovesToWorkAsAHumanAlarm(60 * 60 * 9, callMeBackPleaseAndSayWakeUp);
```

Callbacks are base mechanisms for loosely coupled pieces of application to interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine some function that takes time to be finished, like `setTimeout` inside a function, so you want to make some other function run after that `setTimeout` is finished. You can't do it with just calling function one after another, because it will only start the countdown and move on to the next function. So you need to make function inside that `setTimeout` and pass a function as an argument in first calling, AKA callback function.

Now you would think, 'but I can simply insert a block of code inside `setTimeout` function like this'

```
function doItAfterMinute(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        //block of code
    },60000)
}
```

True, but what if you have 10 different functions to be done after a minute, you won't make 10 `setTimeout` functions with 10 different names?
That is the case where callback shows its power.

```
function doItAfterMinute(cb){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        cb()
    },60000)
}
```

`doItAfterMinute(()=>{ console.log('hey, minute passed!))
 doItAfterMinute(()=>{ console.log('hey, another minute!))`

Comment: The general callback pattern is not concerned with async vs. sync: the only thing that makes the callback pattern the callback pattern is that instead of sending signals back to the caller of a function, that function instead sends its signals to the (or various) callback function(s).

Answer (score 0):

> And I would use these callback functions for the purpose of waiting for the data needed from another function, to make my callback work?

That is one common use case: you are waiting for data that won't be available until some future time.

Another use case: you simply need notification that something happened.  A process has completed successfully (or unsuccessfully), and you want to update the UI.

Still another: you need to be informed that some amount of time has passed.  `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are perfect examples.

To try it, bring up the console on your browser (⌘-Alt-I on a Mac; Ctrl-Shift-I or something on other machines) and type the following:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("Two seconds later"), 2000);
```

and two seconds later...